# Desactivar Layout por defecto en VueJs

Tags: vue.js, laravel-jetstream, inertia.js

Estoy construyendo una aplicación en inertiaJs, tengo por defecto un componente AppLayout, pero esto hace que todos mis componentes se carguen sobre ese.

busco poder evitar eso en un componente en especifico

app.js

```
new Vue({
    store,
    metaInfo: {
        titleTemplate: (title) => title ? `${title} | EVPIU` : 'EVPIU'
    },
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: name => {
                    const componentOptions = require(`./Pages/${name}`).default;
                    componentOptions.layout = (h, page) => h(AppLayout, [page]);

                    return componentOptions;
                },
            },
        }),
}).$mount(app);
```

vale la pena aclarar que es una aplicación hecha con [Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/introduction.html) y Inertia.Js

Answer (score 0):

Solucione este problema de la siguiente forma:

app.js

```
new Vue({
    store,
    metaInfo: {
        titleTemplate: (title) => title ? `${title} | EVPIU` : 'EVPIU'
    },
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                //resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
                resolveComponent: (name)=> {
                    const module = require(`./Pages/${name}`);
                    if(!module.default.layout) {
                        // there is no Layout defined, set the default layout
                        module.default.layout = AppLayout;
                    }
                    return module.default;

                },
            },
        }),
}).$mount(app);
```

solo carga el Applayout cuando no se tiene ningun layout en el component (la mayoria de los casos), luego cree un appLayoutBank y lo cargue en el componente y con eso se resolvio mi problema